# What's the name of the surface resulting from rotating the exponential curve?

Tags: geometry, surfaces

In three dimensions, if we rotate the curve $(x,0,e^x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ around the axis through the points $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,0,0)$ by the angle $2\pi$, what's the resulting surface called?

It resembles a hyperboloid at first glance, but it's generatrix is different.

Comment: You should make clear the domain for $x$ and the rotation angle, which I'm assuming is $2\pi$?

Comment: @rodger_kicks thanks

Comment: What prompted you to think there's a name for this? One can pick any "nice" function and construct a surface of revolution through any axis in a similar fashion. What's so special about this one?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I'm working on a publication where such a surface occurs and want to name it correctly.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin This said, I'd also be thankful for related references.